# C#: Remove Read-only attribute from File without Administrative Privilege

Tags: c#, file, attributes, readonly

Is there a way to remove read-only attribute of a file if the user is not an administrator?

This works if you're an admin but what if you're not?

```
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
myFile.IsReadOnly = false;
```

Comment: That works if you have read/write permission on file. The administrator role is not the key.

Comment: This is a permissions issue, not an Admin/non Admin issue, per se. If the user account you're running under has the "Write Attributes" permission on the file, they'll be able to make this change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need  to have read/write permission on the file.

I preferably use a method like this:

```
FileSystemInfo fsi = new FileSystemInfo(pathToFile);
fsi.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
```

or

```
File.SetAttributes(pathToFile, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

But as I've said, this won't be possible without read/write permissions on the specific file.